# Gas reporter does not report gas usage for low level calls

Tags: gas, hardhat, test

I am using npx hardhat test  command to get the gas usages analysis. My configuration to get the report is like below. In my tests. I have tests for deployment, functions calls, but also some other tests such as low level calls such as storage_reading or calling functions from a third party library PushNotification Service. Although, I have these tests, my gas report does not include any rows for these tests. One sample test function is below written for storage reading test

```
describe("MultiChainCommunity Storage Reading", function () {
  it("should read storage successfully", async function () {
    // Replace with your actual contract address
    // const contractAddress = HARD_HAT_COMMUNITY_IMPLEMENTATION_ADDRESS;
    // const web3 = new Web3(HARD_HAT_RPC_URL);
    // const storageIndex = HARD_HAT_STORAGE_1_INDEX;

    const contractAddress = GOERLI_COMMUNITY_IMPLEMENTATION_ADDRESS;
    const web3 = new Web3(GOERLI_RPC_URL);
    const storageIndex = GOERLI_STORAGE_1_INDEX;
    try {
      const storageValue = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, storageIndex);
      console.log(`Storage value at index ${storageIndex}: ${storageValue}`);

      // Add more storage queries or assertions as needed
      // const anotherStorageValue = await web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, ANOTHER_STORAGE_INDEX);
      // console.log(`Another storage value: ${anotherStorageValue}`);
      
      // Perform assertions or additional logic based on the storage values

      console.log('Storage reading test passed.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading storage:', error);
      throw new Error('Storage reading test failed.');
    }
  });
});
```

I need someone who can help me to get gas analysis for these type of low level or external calls made from ts script?
Regards,
Ferda

```
>   gasReporter: {
>     enabled: true,
>     currency: 'USD',
>     outputFile: "gas_reporter_matic1.txt",
>     noColors: false, 
>     coinmarketcap:process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
>     //token:'ETH',
>     src:"contracts",
>     excludeContracts:[..]
> 
>   },
```

Comment: `getStorageAt` doesn't cost gas. What are you expecting from it?

Comment: some rows showing 0 cost at least ...

Comment: No, gas is only applicable when you send a transaction to the blockchain, in other words, write something to the blockchain. Reading operations doesn't cost any gas.

Comment: I was mostly concerned to find a way to add rows from non function calls. Anyways, thanks